# Using GAP to compute the abelianization of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, computational-mathematics, gap, computational-algebra

Let $K$ be the group generated by four elements $x_1,\cdots,x_4$ with relations that each generator commutes with all its conjugates. (An equivalent relation is, any simple commutator with repeated generator is trivial; for example, $[[x_2,[x_1,x_3]],x_3]=1$.) It can be proved that $K$ is finitely presented.

Let $A$ be the subgroup of $K$ generated by the following elements:

- $x_1x_2x_3x_4$;
- $[x_1,x_2][x_1,x_3][x_1,x_4][x_2,x_3][x_2,x_4][x_3,x_4]$;
- $[x_1,x_2,x_3][x_1,x_2,x_4][x_1,x_3,x_4][x_2,x_3,x_4]$;
- $[x_1,x_3,x_2][x_1,x_4,x_2][x_1,x_4,x_3][x_2,x_4,x_3]$;
- $[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$;
- $[x_1,x_2,x_4,x_3]$;
- $[x_1,x_3,x_2,x_4]$;
- $[x_1,x_3,x_4,x_2]$;
- $[x_1,x_4,x_2,x_3]$;
- $[x_1,x_4,x_3,x_2]$.

Now I would like to compute the abelianization of $A$; namely, the group $A/[A,A]$, where $[A,A]$ is the commutator subgroup of $A$. My question is:

---

**Is there any way that I can use GAP to find the abelianization of $A$?**

---

As I never used GAP before, I am not familiar with how to input my question into GAP. A note of my notation: in my question $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $[a,b,c,d]$ means $[[[a,b],c],d]$. If it is hopeless to apply GAP to my problem, is there any way that I can attack my problem by hand?

Comment: Once you have the group $A$ in GAP, you can get the commutator subgroup with the command DerivedSubgroup, and then ask GAP to compute the quotient.

Comment: As I am a beginner of GAP, my main difficulty is inputting my group $K$ and $A$ into it. Is there any example or template for me to follow?

Comment: There's a short example of inputting a group via generators and relations [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Gap3/Manual3/C023S000.htm).

Comment: You're gonna need that finite presentation of K to do this in GAP. You're also gonna need A to be finite index.

Comment: @tobias I think it's quicker to do AbelianInvariants(A)

Comment: @SteveD Ahh, nice. I didn't know that one.

Comment: @aPaulT: BTW, that's the link to the manual for GAP3, which was superseded by GAP4 in 1999 (though this example does work in GAP4).

Comment: @Zuriel: have you already managed to construct _K_ in GAP?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov, not yet. I am trying to work out the relations on $K$. It seems that there are so many (dozens of?) relations in $K$ and I am not sure if GAP will be happy with that. Practically speaking, is having dozens of relations a problem to GAP?

Comment: @Zuriel: hard to say, one would have to construct the group first to try. There may be both easy and hard examples with both small and large number of relations. Also, if there is an equivalent way of formulating relations, maybe worth to try both approaches. In addition, I think to construct _K_ and make it sure that none of the relations is lost, you have to do it programmatically in a loop. Useful function on this way is `Comm(a,b)` which returns `a^-1*b^-1*a*b`

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderKonovalov!! Now my main concern is to simplify the relations. I have asked in a seperate question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521322/simplifying-relations-in-a-group. May I clarify what you mean by "do it programmatically in a loop"?

Comment: @Zuriel: I mean create a list `r` of relations and then do something like `for <some combination of gens> do Add( r, <some word in gens>) od;`

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov, it seems that $A$ has infinite index in $K$. In this case, is it still possible to use GAP to obtain information about $A$?

Comment: @Zuriel: hmm, it depends on which kind of information you'd like to obtain...

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov, I am maily interested in finding out the abelianization of $A$. Someone says that it is not possible if $A$ is of infinite index; what do you think?