# Simplifying Relations in a Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, computability, gap, computational-algebra

Let $K$ be the group generated by four elements $x_1,\cdots,x_4$ with relations that any simple commutator with repeated generator is trivial; for example, $[[x_2,[x_1,x_3]],x_3]=1$. As I have asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519971/using-gap-to-compute-the-abelianization-of-a-subgroup), I am trying to use GAP to do some calculation with $K$. Now one problem is that there are too many relations. For example, all following are relations in $K$:

- $[[[[x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}],x_{\sigma(3)}],x_{\sigma(4)}],x_i]=1$, where $\sigma\in S_4$, the symmetric group on four letters $\{1,2,3,4\}$
  and $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.
- $[[[x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}],x_{\sigma(3)}],x_i]=1$, where $\sigma\in S_3$, the symmetric group on three letters $\{1,2,3\}$
  and $i\in\{1,2,3\}$. And by replacing $\{1,2,3\}$ by other three-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, there are some more relations.
- $[[x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}],x_i]=1$, where $\sigma\in S_2$, the symmetric group on two letters $\{1,2\}$
  and $i\in\{1,2\}$. And by replacing $\{1,2\}$ by other two-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, there are some more relations.

Now my question is:

1. Is there any way that I can reduce the number of relations? I believe that some relations here must be redundant.
2. Is it pratical to use GAP to do calculation with $K$? I am worried that too many defining relations may make the calculation impractical.

Comment: It might be worth to look at [Presentations and Tietze Transformations](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap48.html) from the GAP manual. Also, the GAP package [kbmag](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/kbmag.html) may be more efficient for some presentations. In general, that does not sound like impractical from the beginning.

Comment: Write $[y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n]$ to mean a commutator of length $n$ (brackets places arbitrarily). Then any commutator of length greater than five is redundant. This is because such a commutator will contain a commutator of length five, and so your long commutator is saying "this element commutes with the identiy". Which is obviously true. (You don't make it obvious from your post that you know this...I suspect you do though...anyway, my point is that you only have to worry about finitely many relators...)

Comment: I would be inclined to write a GAP program to construct the set of relators, rather than trying to type them all in yourself.

Comment: @user1729, thanks for pointing this out. I am actually aware that any commutator of length greater than five is redundant so that there are only finitely many relations. My problem is, even if there only finitely many relations, there could be dozens of relations and I am not sure if too many relations will make the calculation impractical.

Comment: @DerekHolt, what kind of GAP program can construct the set of relators in my example? Do you have any example of that?

Comment: You can get down to $300=5!$. This is because $[a, b]^{-1}=[b, a]$ which means that the orders of the brackets don't matter (when thinking about relators). To see this, consider the following example: $[[b, c], a]^{-1}=[a, [b, c]]$ and so the relator $[a, [b, c]]$ is a consequence of $[[b, c], a]$. If your relator has length four then just use the fact that $[a, b]=1\Leftrightarrow [a, b]^{-1}=1$. That gives you 300=5! relators, and these all have the form $[[[a, b], c], d]$ but you can now just write them as $[a, b, c, d]$ unambiguously.

Comment: Actually, sorry, the above comment only cuts down the relators of length 4 in a practical way. You can apply it to relators of length 5 and 3, but less effectively. Also, I think you don't actually get 4! relators (the 5 should have been a 4). That was my poor logic. Also, apparently I cannot compute 5!.

Comment: @zuriel: sorry, but I am not volunteering to write a GAP program for you! I was thinking that if you have a relation as word in the group generators $g[1],g[2],\ldots$, then it is not diffcult to apply elements of $S_4$ to the indices and generate the ssame relation with the generators permuted. There is a GAP forum mailing list which you could try if you want detailed help with writing programs.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt! Yes, my main difficulty is writing the program. Will seek for help from the forum then. Thanks!